# how to reload the selected tab jquery

Tags: jquery

how to reload the selected tab actually i having problem in reloading part.
when i add my data i'll successfully saved in datatable but in id field in database it shows proper id but when i add the detail its not shows id in datatable.

(before refresh the summary tab)
here is example it shows something like this in datatable
id  patient husband age ...........so on...
     xyz     abc     23....... so on...

(after refreshing manually)
but when i refresh my page it show successfully..like this in datatable:
id  patient husband age   ...........so on...
13     xyz     abc   23   ....... so on...

but exactly i want when i add my detail it will automatically refresh the selected tab.

here is my code as below:

```
<button type="button"  a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnClickAddRow();">Add Summary</button>

function fnClickAddRow(event) {

$('#table_scroll').dataTable().fnAddData( [

"",$('#patientt').val(),$('#husband').val(),$('#age').val(),$('#opu_no').val(),$('#date').val(),$('#proc').val(),$('#no_of_eggs').val(),$('#fert').val(),$('#et_date').val(),$('#et_day').val(),$('#et').val(),$('#fz').val(),$('#bioch_preg').val(),$('#clin_preg').val(),$('#fh').val(),$('#comment').val()

]);


var datastring = $(Form_summary).serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "summaryajax.php",
    data: datastring, 
    success: function(response){

 alert(response);

    }
    });
```

Comment: can you add your Tabs code/markup? are you using jQuery UI Tabs?

Comment: yes im using jquery ui tabs the problem is when i click the summary button it show the data without showing id but  on refresh  it show proper id in datables dnt getting exactly.. help. thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax success event, instead of alert add the below. It will load your tab.

```
$('tabSelector').tabs( "load" , indexOfYourDataTableTab )
```

But I think, you can just reload your datatable or update id column of that newly inserted row instead reloading the entire tab.

Otherwise, first post your data to PHP file & get newly inserted ID in response, then add row into data table

```
function fnClickAddRow(event) {

var datastring = $(Form_summary).serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "summaryajax.php",
    data: datastring, 
    success: function(response){
       $('#table_scroll').dataTable().fnAddData( 
          [response, $('#patientt').val(), $('#husband').val(),$('#age').val(),
            $('#opu_no').val(), $('#date').val(),$('#proc').val(), $('#no_of_eggs').val(), 
            $('#fert').val(),$('#et_date').val(), $('#et_day').val(), $('#et').val(), 
            $('#fz').val(), $('#bioch_preg').val(), $('#clin_preg').val(), $('#fh').val(), 
            $('#comment').val() ]);
    }
});
```

Comment: can u plz elaborate indexOfYourDataTableTab with example im not getting this im new to this. how to apply this..??

Comment: if your datatable is in 2nd tab, then indexOfYourDataTableTab will be 1. In jQuery UI, tab indexes start from 0.

Comment: What abt second approach? Post the form using AJAX first, then add row to DATATABLE.

Comment: yes i tried that second approach also but on submit the button the data is not shown in datatable but when i refresh my page the data which i added is there..  same problem :( no success..